# Folder permissions on shared NTFS media partition

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, permissions, ntfs, bittorrent

My HDD has a NTFS media partition shared between Win and Linux partitions.

When my bittorrent client on Windows 8.1 (Tribler) is set to save files in the Downloads folder located on that partition and I try to download a file, I get an 'insufficient writing permission error'. Through right clicking and properties, I changed to permissions for the whole volume AND for the folder but it doesn't seem to do anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could try using the `TAKEOWN` command to recursively take ownership of all files in the volume and then grant yourself 'special permissions' or 'full control'.

I'm unsure what this would do to your linux access though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. First make sure you apply the permissions to child folders and files **locally** (NTFS permission). THEN make sure you have the sharing permissions set accordingly.

If it still doesn't work then perhaps the firewall may be blocking the access.

Disable the Windows firewall completely just to be sure it is not the firewall.